# Drawing an arc with SCNShape and UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

I am trying to draw a piece of pie in `SCNShape` using the following code:

```
UIBezierPath *piePiece = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[piePiece addArcWithCenter: CGPointZero radius:  0.150 startAngle: 0.0 endAngle: M_PI/6  clockwise: YES];
[piePiece closePath];
SCNShape *pieShape = [SCNShape shapeWithPath: piePiece extrusionDepth: 0];
pieShape.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIColor blueColor];
pieShape.firstMaterial.doubleSided = YES;
SCNNode *pieNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry: pieShape];
```

But I get the following shape:

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9Yum.png)
I don't see the arc. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You must change the flatness of the UIBezierPath to a lower value. In Swift:

```
pieShape.flatness = 0.0003
```